# calculating circuit for NiCr at a set temp

Tags: heat

This may be a primer for most, but this is the first time working with resistance wire and I'm unfamiliar with it's qualities

I want to create a circuit that will heat a length of wire to a set temp.

My question:  With a supply of 12vdc is it possible to calculate what resistance is needed to heat a 20ft length of wire to a temp of 90 degF?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @PlasmaHH : I agree - but  I'm impressed : how did you fool the 16 char minimum?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I did not, I typed in 16 chars... unicode is such a nice tool sometimes...

Comment: "I want to create a circuit that will heat a length of wire to a set temp." For what purpose? Why does it have to be 90 degF?

Comment: Can you provide the information for the wire? A link to a datasheet, or at least the specific type and diameter? The wire will have a very specific resistance at 90F. So you may be able to design a feedback circuit that can stabilizes it at 90F.

Comment: Considering 20awg flat NiCr .81mm and .814Ω/ft. Building a heater for my SUV hatchback lift pistons, which only work well when room temp. Would wrap wire around hi-temp sleeve that slips over piston. 90ºF is the highest temp comfortable with heating the piston without risking burning the skin. Already have control circuitry to turn on/off based on temp.

Comment: The resistance tempco for NiCr is not as high as I somehow thought. Only 400 ppm / K. My original idea was that you could use a circuit that measures the resistance of the wire somehow, and stabilizes the current at the level needed for 90F wire temperature. But I now think that is not workable.

Answer (score 1):

I was kinda thinking along those lines, assuming I could determine the resistance of the wire when it was at the desired temp. Since this is an automotive effort, the voltage is fairly stable. Worse case would be to experiment with various resistors to get the desired temp.